# Writing to files through postscript via pstricks

Tags: pstricks, postscript, auto-pst-pdf

I want to use file operations in postscript: right now I need them to print large debugging data, which otherwise I have to copy and paste from the standard output.

More importantly, in the future, I want to use file operations to cache results of large computations (for example, a rendered 3d figure).

However, the code below does not work. I checked using my gs interpreter: when the code is directly executed via gs, it creates a file successfully. What is the issue? How can I gain standard postscript file access via LaTeX/pstricks? Thanks!

**Answer by AlexG (many thanks!)** compile with

```
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER
pdflatex -shell-escape
```

[Edit:] after a tiny bit of digging into the documentation of auto-pst-pdf I found out what options to turn on to make it work with pdflatex as well :)

That appears to solve the problem! Have not tested the remaining file operations yet. The file needs to be closed too.

```
%Compile with: 
%    pdflatex -shell-escape   
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[dvips={-o -Ppdf}, pspdf={-dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None}, pdfcrop={}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\pstVerb{ 
(./myFile.txt) (w) file 
closefile
}
\phantom{A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The issue appears to be one of file access permissions: the error I get is from the postscript interpretter:

```
This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software
(www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2014.10.09:1519' ->
using-files-pstricks-autopp.ps

</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>

</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1]

Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file-- Operand stack: (./myFile.txt)
(w) Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval--
--nostringval-- --nos

tringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval--
--nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1916 1 3 %oparray_pop 1915 1 3
%oparray_pop 1899 1 3 %oparray_pop 1787 1 3 %oparray_pop
--nostringval-- %errorexec_pop .runexec2 --nostringval--
--nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval--
Dictionary stack: --dict:1176/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)--
--dict:118/200(L)-- --dict:100/300(L)-- Current allocation mode is
local Last OS error: No such file or directory Current file position
is 85884 GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Prozess endete normal
```

On tangentially related note, here's the kind of image I am computing and need to cache. This is an example of a  Moebius strip, but I can plot arbitrary geometry with reasonably accurate Z-buffering. My contours are much finer than what you get with a simple triangle mesh (my mesh interior is a straight line approximation, but the contours are sampled much finer). Notice how all contour lines on the background are drawn with a dotted line.

[image: a Moebius strip rendered by my code]

The 3d library is rather long, contained here: 
[the needed pstricks-commands.sty file](https://sourceforge.net/p/freecalculus/code/653/tree/trunk/lectures/pstricks-commands.sty)

Modulo my library, here's what the code for drawing the strip will look like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[dvips={-o -Ppdf}, pspdf={-dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None}, pdfcrop={}]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{../pstricks-commands}
%file pstricks-commands to be found here:
%https://sourceforge.net/p/freecalculus/code/651/tree/trunk/lectures/pstricks-commands.sty
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1, -1)(2,2)
\fcBoundingBox{-3}{-3}{4}{4} %
\fcStartIIIdScene%
\fcSurfaceInScene[iterationsU=33, iterationsV=5]{0}{-1}{360}{1}{%
[10 dict begin
/R 2 def
/r {0.8 v mul} def
/theta u def
/phi {u 0.5 mul} def
/A {phi cos r mul R add} def
theta cos A mul theta sin A mul phi sin r mul
end %
]%
}%
\fcFinishIIIdScene % <- this operation is really expensive.
%need to cache it's output so that it's computed only once for a given input.
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you compiling this will all the goodies enabled? `--enable-write18` and/or `--shell-escape`?

Comment: Yes, the -shell-escape option is set.

Comment: That may just be it - it's not allowed. Someone with more PS knowledge can chime in...

Comment: @Werner `ps2pdf -dNOSAFER ...`, perhaps.

Comment: -dNOSAFER solved the problem for the dvi->ps->pdf toolchain, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexG Would you mind making that an answer so we can get it out of the question?

Comment: I don't understand, am I supposed to not answer the question inside the first post? I am new to stackexchange, don't know what the protocol is

Comment: @user39417 That's correct. It would be better to have all the *answers* in the answer part of the page. But it's fine to update the question in light of the answer as you have done. Sean was just suggesting to Alex that the comment was significant enough that it could/should be in an *answer*, not just a *comment*.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no real sense to use it with `pst-pdf`. However, you have to use 
the `postscript` environment and a dummy character inside this 
environment because it will be inserted as an image later.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[pspdf={-dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None}, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
\pstVerb{ 
  /DataFile (myFile.txt) (w) file def 
DataFile (foo) writestring
DataFile (bar) writestring
DataFile closefile
}
\phantom{A}
\end{postscript}

foo
\end{document}
```

It works for me with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

Comment: "It makes no real sense to use it with pst-pdf". I understand that pst-pdf uses on the background the dvi->ps->pdf toolchain, so technically running with pdf-latex is redundant. However, I am making lecture slides being compiled on various machines by various people with even more varying technical skills. If someone checks out my repo and compiles with pdflatex, I want no error messages displayed. Would save me 15 minutes of emailing and explanations every time I get a new user of the slides!